# Star micronics center image

Tags: java, printing, receipt

Im trying to center a image on 80mm paper but it its always in the left position this is what i tried. Thanks

```
 AssetManager assetManager = mContext.getAssets();
    InputStream istr = null;
    try {
        istr = assetManager.open("www/img/logo.jpg");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);

    StarBitmap starbitmap = new StarBitmap(bm, false, 200);
    commands.add(new byte[] { 0x1b, 0x61, 0x01 }); //align center
    commands.add(starbitmap.getImageEscPosDataForPrinting(false,true));
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making the graphic the size of the paper. So i use 3 inch 80mm so i made the graphic 1200 width by 250 height and centered my image on that canvas that centered the image for me.